# Start Apache in background with batch file

Tags: windows, apache, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that will start Apache, and the open `http://localhost` in the web browser. In its simplest form:

```
@start apache\bin\httpd.exe
@start http://localhost
```

This causes the batch file to run Apache, open the web page, and exit. However, the `httpd.exe` opens in its own terminal window, instead of opening hidden in the background. How can I make it open with no visible windows?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
@start /b "" apache\bin\httpd.exe
```

Comment: Thank-you! I was convinced that it was a setting I needed to pass to `httpd.exe` - I didn't think of seeing what `start` could offer

Comment: That's strange… using this, the Apache window is hidden but a blank cmd window stays open. Do you have any idea how to remedy this?

Comment: Try to set an `exit` on the last line of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Seen this on another site. It might work.

start it in the background:

```
command &
```

then run:

```
disown
```

and close the terminal.

You can stop a foregrounded application with Ctrl+z, then start it in the background (foreground) with the bg (fg) command.