# When I run Java from a batch file, can I hook a batch file to force exit?

Tags: java

I create a directory in a Java file and delete it when done.

If I quit during Java work, of course it will not perform the deletion.

I've used addShutdownHook() but it seems to work fine with a shutdown command.

My forced shutdown means when i closing the running batch file window. (:when push X button)

Is there a way to solve it in Java source?

It is my tried source

```
.
.
.
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(new File(basePath));
                }
            });
.
.
.
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404712/java-shutdown-hook-not-run?rq=1 and take a look at the answer of Nilesh Jadav. Shutdown Hooks are not guaranteed to be executed.

Comment: It sounds like you want to avoid the cmd window when you run java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605467/start-apache-in-background-with-batch-file When you ask the os to kill a process, it does it with varying degrees of severity. If the window isn't present, then it is easier to not close the cmd prompt window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not think of a pure java solution. The problem is, if your program is forced to shutdown, e.g. with `kill -9` (SIGKILL), there is no chance for your program to hook in between. It will shutdown immediately.

You could use monitoring tools like [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) or [deamontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) or [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to perform clean-up operations as soon as your program has been shutdown.

You can also provide a handmade solution like suggested here: [Shell Script For Process Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207248/shell-script-for-process-monitoring) , e.g. using tools like `watch`.